# Python error 1064 on SQL statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting the following error. I am using Python 3.4.

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username = %s", un)
```

Comment: just a variable holding the users input of their username

Comment: Ok please try: `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username = %s", (un,))`

Comment: Please list the definition of your table and also how you populate `un` (both in the question, not in a comment por favor)

Comment: duly noted, this is my first question on here. I'm also just now realizing that how I populate un may also be part of the issue, but I have it working as of now. Thanks for your comment @flaschbier

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue but i don't fully understand why or how. Setting the cursor buffer and changing the execute line to bernie's suggestion solves the issue

```
cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username = %s", (un,))
```

Thank you everyone for your comments!